# Proving $\sin^2x<\sin x$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

Actually this is a calculus problem. I'm required to compare a given integral with a simpler one and check if the inequality holds [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lmmy.png). (Question b)

This is a part of an answer in my textbook:

$$0 < \sin x < 1 \;\;\text{on}\;\; (0,\pi) \quad\implies \sin^2x<\sin x \;\;\text{on}\;\; (0,\pi)$$
Then it says, Therefore:$$\int ^{\pi }_{0}\sin^{2} xdx< \int ^{\pi }_{0}\sin xdx$$

But how can prove this inequality? $$\sin^{2} x< \sin x\ (x\in \ ( 0,\ \pi ))$$ if $$0 < \sin x < 1 \;\;\text{on}\;\; (0,\pi)$$

*Edit: Thank you for warning me about the MSE format. I'll be more careful in the future.*

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Note that the strict inequality is not true for $x\in(0,\pi)$: consider $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Note you don't use trigonometry at all.  If $0 < w < 1$ then $0*w < w*w < 1*w$ and $0 < w^2 < w$.  Just replace $w$ with $\sin x$.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: But how do you know that $$if\ 0\ < \ w\ < \ 1\ then\ 0\ < \ w^{2} < w$$

Comment: For $0<w<1$, if we multiply it all by w as we know that w is positive, we get $0<w^2<w$ that is how we know it

Comment: Omg, how could I missed that... Thank you so much Asv and fleablood!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all.  $0 < \sin x < 1$ on $(0,\pi)$ is *not* true because $\sin \frac {\pi} 2 = 1$.

But we *do* have $0 < \sin x \le 1$ on $(0,\pi)$ with $\sin x = 1 \iff x = \frac \pi 2$.

And we *do* have $0< \sin^2 x < \sin x < 1$ for all $x\in (0,1); x\ne \frac \pi 2$ (And $\sin^2 x = \sin x = 1$ if $x =\frac \pi 2$)

But that has Nothing to do with trigonometry!

Notice for *any*  $0 < w < 1$ then if we multiply each term by $w$ we *ALWAYS* get:

$0*w < w*w < 1*w$ and $0 < w^2 < w$.

And so $0 < \sin x < 1$ if $x\ne \frac {\pi}2$ we *will* hgave $0 < \sin^2 x < \sin x$ when $x\ne \frac {\pi}2 $.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x)$ has the range of $(0, 1]$ when $x\in (0, \pi)$

Now you can see that for any number in $(0, 1]$, taking the square means multiplying by a number which is smaller than or equal to 1, therefore the square will be a number smaller than the original number.

However, the question you asked doesn't hold true as adam pointed out, $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$ therefore $\sin^2(x)\le \sin(x)$ would be true, not $\sin^2(x)<\sin(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sin x$ is a positive number on this interval.  Try dividing both sides by $\sin x$.

Answer (score 0):

In this interval $\sin(x)$ is positive. Also $0\leq\sin(x)\leq 1$, so it is a fraction like:

$\sin(x)= \frac 1a$

$\sin^2(x)=\frac 1{a^2}$

where $ a \geq 1$

If $a>1$ then $a^2>a$ , therefore:

$ \frac 1{a^2}<\frac 1a$

$\Rightarrow\sin^2(x)<\sin(x)$

$\sin^2(x)=\sin(x)$ if $a=1$